Web scraping with Python BeautifulSoup
I would like to collect data by web scraping with Python BeautifulSoup from the website for my data analysis project.
the data I want to collect from the website;

date: 06.07.2027
Stage: Berghain, Panorama Bar, Garten
Timetable
Artist
Labels

eventually I want to transfer the data to SQL to build this sample table
sample table
I'm very stuck in the first step in web scraping.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.berghain.berlin/en/event/77218/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find('div', class_='running-order-set__info').find('span').contents[0]

result: 'Norman Nodge'
I was only managed to get first artist name..
and don't know how to collect other informations!
any kind soul can help poor student trying to do some fun project?
** UPDATE
I was able to solve it with @Andrej Kesely answer.
I adjust a bit to fit into dataframe.
dates = []
names = []
stages = []
times = []
artists = []
notes = []

for li in soup.select('main li'):
    date = li.find_previous('p')
    dates.append(date.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split()[1])

    name = li.find_previous('h1')
    names.append(name.get_text(strip=True))

    stage = li.find_previous('h2')
    stages.append(stage.get_text(strip=True))

    time = li.time.text
    times.append(time)

    artist = li.select_one('.running-order-set__info span')
    artists.append(artist.contents[0] if artist.contents else 'NaN')

    notes.append(artist.span.text if artist.span else 'NaN')

bh_df = pd.DataFrame(
{'date': dates,
'party_name': names,
'stage': stages,
'start_time': times,
'artist_name': artists,
'note': notes
})

result:


Use find_all() to find all elements that match the criteria, then loop over them.

You can try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.berghain.berlin/en/event/77218/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for li in soup.select("main li"):
    date = li.find_previous("p")
    name = li.find_previous("h1")
    stage = li.find_previous("h2")
    time = li.time.text
    artist = li.select_one(".running-order-set__info span")

    print("Date  ", date.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ").split()[1])
    print("Name  ", name.get_text(strip=True))
    print("Stage ", stage.get_text(strip=True))
    print("Time  ", time)
    print("Artist", artist.contents[0] if artist.contents else "-")
    print("Note  ", artist.span.text if artist.span else "-")

    print("-" * 80)

Prints:
Date   06.07.2024                           
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   23:59    
Artist Norman Nodge 
Note   Ostgut Ton
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024      
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   04:30    
Artist Alienata    
Note   -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   08:30    
Artist UVB         
Note   Mord 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   12:30    
Artist Matthew Cha 
Note   -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   16:30    
Artist Gaetano Parisio
Note   -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024         
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   20:30    
Artist Justine Perry
Note   -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Berghain  
Time   00:30    
Artist DJ Nobu 
Note   Bitta
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht                                                                                         
Stage  Panorama Bar                            
Time   23:59
Artist Lauer 
Note   Live at Robert Johnson / Running Back
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Panorama Bar
Time   04:00
Artist Dam Swindle 
Note   Heist Recordings
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Panorama Bar
Time   08:00
Artist Kikelomo
Note   -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Panorama Bar
Time   12:30
Artist -
Note   -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Panorama Bar
Time   19:30
Artist Wallace
Note   -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Panorama Bar
Time   00:00
Artist Cinthie 
Note   803 Crystal Grooves
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Garten
Time   12:00
Artist Suze Ijó
Note   -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date   06.07.2024
Name   Klubnacht
Stage  Garten
Time   16:00
Artist Hiroko Yamamura
Note   -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

